# Problems installing packages from downloaded files using terminal

Tags: command-line, compiling

I am facing Problems installing packages from downloaded files using terminal. for ex - I downloaded goobox-2.2.0.tar.gz , i extracted using archive manager. Then i opened terminal in folder and typed -

./ configure but then an error pops up permission is denied. I wanted to know how to install programs using terminal and how i can rectify the problems ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to make the configure file executable - open a terminal, cd to the extracted folder and run the following and see how you get on:

```
sudo chmod a+x configure
```

Comment: what is a+x . I am a beginner for terminal

Comment: Wise to be cautious : essentially it's saying 'add execute permissions for all users'. (the a standing for 'all' and the x denoting e'x'ecute)

Comment: ... to remove execute from all users you would use a-x.

Comment: No its still not working. Even logging in as root it give same error (permission denied) while opening terminal in required folder

Comment: Odd - I just downloaded it from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/goobox/2.2/ and not only was the configure file already executable I was able to run it (although I don't have some of the dependencies so it didn't complete)

Comment: why use a+x when a u+x would work just fine.

Comment: Why are you prefixing it with sudo? That's not needed

Comment: @tinhed: a+x is just belt and braces approach, if it worked then he could have wound it back.

Comment: @bilal: sudo may not be needed but there is not normally any harm in doing so. Probably overkill and just force of habit.

Comment: now error is like this after downloading specified file-        No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Comment: still not working can somebody help.

Answer (score 1):

The file `configure` doesn't seem to have the execute (+x) mode set. Without that mode, the system won't execute the file. Set it by running this command:

```
chmod a+x configure
```

After that you can build and install this package by running these commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Downloading the package and extracting it showed the the execute flag is indeed set (see my comments in my answer). He has already tried the a+x command and still has the problem (see his comments in my answer)

Comment: There is no need to install goobox . I just want to learn how to install any .tz package. I have tried many packets but they give same error permission denied even while running as root. I'm using linux mint 10 same derivative of debian as ubuntu